# What would happen after Bitlocker put the system into recovery mode

Tags: linux, bitlocker

What would happen after Bitlocker put the system into recovery mode?

I find it wasn't clear in all the materials that I read. This one, https://superuser.com/questions/627102/bitlocker-asks-for-recovery-key-and-starts-automatic-recovery, describe the situation clearly, but I suppose it shouldn't be that way, right?

Moreover, once the recovery password has been correctly provided and the recovery mode is over, will it ask for recovery password again on next boot up? From http://www.geekpeek.net/bitlocker-dual-boot-windows7-fedora/, "If you run Windows 7, BitLocker will ask you to enter the recovery key", I have the impression that it will.

Comment: So you are confirming that, once Bitlocker is in recovery mode due to whatever reason (e.g., HW changes), it will remains in recovery mode forever, and need you to input recovery password every time?

Comment: I asked because your answer was not clear to me, and neither the 2nd answer, which is more insulting than helping. Anyway, I've found the answer myself -- **Bitlocker always asking for Recoverykey after made chainges** in Winboot.exe, http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732774.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Speaking from the strictly theoretical point of view, if altering a partition will cause Bitlocker to ask for your recovery key, it's probably going to continue asking for it until the "error" is corrected.

And I would correct the "error" as quickly as possible, decrypting the data, and re-encrypting it with the new set of rules. Or deciding to use a different encryption tool that knows how to not depend on sources of entropy not changing. (Especially since entropy implies change.) Or deciding not to keep data around that needs encryption in such large amounts.